# Dart start process stdout multiple chunks

Tags: dart, appwrite

I am trying to automate the process of creating an Appwrite project using Process.start in dart but in stdout I don't get the full output, it comes in chunks and sometimes they contain info from previous chunks. How can i get the full output once?

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  Process process = await Process.start(
    'appwrite',
    ['init', 'project'],
  );

  process.stdout.listen((event) {
    String s = utf8.decode(event);
    print(s);
    if (s.contains('Create a new Appwrite project')) {
      process.stdin.writeln();
    }
  });

  process.stderr.listen((event) {
    String s = utf8.decode(event);
    print(s);
  });
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this will help your problem, but it's normal for output to be chunked; stdout is normally line-buffered.  However, you shouldn't be calling `utf.decode` directly on each chunk since there's no guarantee that chunks are split on code-point boundaries. You instead should use [`Stream.transform`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/transform.html).  You also might want to use `LineSplitter` and to iterate over the `Stream` instead of using `listen`: `var lines = process.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).transform(const LineSplitter()); await for (var line in lines) { ... }`

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks, I tried your approach but with LineSplitter I don't get the last line from the first event (Link this directory to an existing Appwrite project), any idea why?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Appwrite.  If you're trying to read a prompt that isn't terminated by a newline, then yeah, `LineSplitter` won't work.